# laravel-admin use url/prefix 404 not found

Tags: laravel, nginx, sld, laravel-admin

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  www.kakura.com;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;

}


server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  kakura.com www.kakura.com;

    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/json application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/javascript;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/dmwon.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/dmwon.key;
    ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/comic-app/build;    
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /bdo {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/comics/public;
        index  index.php;
    
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass   myphp:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   /var/www/html/comics/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

this is my nginx im trying to use prefix loc to laravel project . the main url is for another project. its both working can access. but the laravel return 404 .  .env APP_URL=https://www.kakura.com/bdo/
i feel its the problem of laravel didnt accept the right args .

try to change the nginx and .env  but still cant access laravel return 404 from it

Comment: .env
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://www.kakura.com/bdo/
ADMIN_HTTPS=true
ADMIN_ROUTE_PREFIX=oa